TomEE 9- WARNING WebContextsService.lazyStartSessionContext Could NOT lazily initialize session context because NO active request context
I recently upgraded tomEE8 to tomEE 9 in my project and see the logs contains this warning. There is nothing breaking in my project but i see lot off logs for this warning.
How can we disable it ??
is disabling a good idea ?


I am seeing this same log after upgrading to TOMEE 9 also.  Wonder if you have found the cause and solution to this warning log?

no i didn't get any solution yet. Please let me know if you get any solution for the same

Not sure if that log has any significant meaning or not.  But since my site has been live for almost 6 months now and has not had any issue, I decided to simply suppress that log by adding the following two lines to conf/logging.properties:
org.apache.webbeans.web.context.WebContextsService.level=SEVERE
org.apache.webbeans.web.context.WebContextsService.handlers=1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.AsyncConsoleHandler



i am still getting that warning even after putting these 2 lines at the end of logging.properties. Is there anything else that i am missing ?

tomee by default uses Java-Util-Logging (JUL) to create logs, and JUL can be configured using logging.properties.  But tomee's default JUL logging can be overridden to use log4j.  If you have overridden your tomee to use jog4j, then those two logging.properties configs might not work for you.  One thing to try is to play with logging.properties to make sure tomee is using it.  For example, you can try changing all the .level values to SEVERE and see if logs get reduced to minimum.  If not, then the logging.propreties might not be in effect.

The trick is to play with the logging.properties and make sure it is controlling your logging before trying those two new lines.

if you are running your tomee from an IDE, the logging.properties might located in somewhere else.  I use Eclipse IDE, the logging.properties is located in [mySandBox]\Servers[myTomeeServer]\logging.properties.

hm,  that message is coming back.  I need to test that out some more.  I will delete this answer if I can't get it to work.  Sorry about that.

@Pinki Sharma I made a small change to those two logging.properties lines.  Would you please try them out?  It is kind of weird because they seem to work when the Tomee is running on the linux server.  But they don't work when I run tomee from my local eclipse, which is a windows.

Sure, i will try them. Thank you for the response
